# Oracle Input Variable =&name Equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to run the below command in Postgres as a piece of dynamic SQL that accepts an input variable on the command line. In Oracle I would use ***='&TABLE_OWNER'*** to prompt and accept a table owner for example but I can't find the equivalent in Postgres?

eg.

In Oracle I would do this:

```
select 'drop table '||owner||'.'||table_name||';' from dba_tables where owner='&TABLE_OWNER';
```

but what would be the equivalent in Postgres?

```
select 'drop table '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||';' from pg_tables where schemaname='<INPUT_VARIABLE>';
```

Comment: Actually the syntax "&variable" is not Oracle RDBMS at all. It is what's called a *substitution variable* and used by various interfacing software (sqlplus,SQL developer, TOAD, most other IDEs). What happens is the interface sees &variable, prompts for a value, and then physically changes the line before submitting to the statement, the RDBMS itself never sees the substitution variable. In fact I sometimes use the exact same format in DBeaver connecting to Postgres. Works just fine.  You just have to always keep in mind what piece of software you are talking too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` variables are referenced with a colon, like `:aname`.

```
\prompt 'gimme the schema name' aname
SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = :'aname';
```

The opening quote has to be *after* the colon.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it'll be the easiest way to try.